# Update a Vertex after Retrieving it

Tags: java, arcadedb

```
String queryPositional="SELECT FROM TestVtx WHERE $xy_io=?";
        rs=db.command("sql", queryPositional, "30");
        while(rs.hasNext()){

            Vertex vtx=rs.next().getVertex().get();
            System.out.println(vtx.toJSON());
            System.out.println(vtx.getClass().getName());//RoteImmutableVertex
//vtx.setProperty("name","value"); vtx.save(); --> No method to update
            
}
```

What is the way to update the retrieved vertex in ArcadeDB

Comment: usually (SQL) you have to send an `UPDATE` statement to the database to change a record, but I do not know ArcadeDB. (Something like `db.command("UPDATE SomeType SET name=? WHERE @RID=?")` [I am guessing the type and the WHERE clause!])

Comment: In OrientDB, it would be vtx.setProperty(name, value).save(). Since ArcadeDB is a fork I was looking for some means of updating vertices which are retrieved with queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcadeDB vertices coming from a query are immutable (unless already modified in the transaction). The right way is to call `.modify()`:

```java
vtx.modify().set("name","value").save();
```